# load symbols using quantmod up to a specific date

Tags: r, quantmod

How would I load the stock data of `AMZN` that does not include the stock prices after `2016-01-12`?

The code to load the most up-to-date stock prices is this
    getSymbols("AMZN", auto.assign = FALSE)
But I want to pretend that today is January 12th and eliminate the prices after that date. What would be the most convenient way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mySeries <- getSymbols("AMZN", auto.assign = FALSE)

t <- mySeries['::2016-01-12']
```

An explanation of subsetting is given here http://www.quantmod.com/examples/data/